# Boto3 UserData script having unexpected behavior for $HOME variable when installing Miniconda in EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, environment-variables, boto3

I'm trying to launch an instance using Boto3 and execute a script using the UserData parameter to install Miniconda. I'm replicating the steps described here:

https://gist.github.com/dcbark01/8133b7b24c4b3a573d23ad03b02d2513

The script I'm using for UserData parameter is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

su - ec2-user

cd /home/ec2-user
    
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_23.3.1-0-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /tmp/miniconda3.sh 2> log_miniconda

bash /tmp/miniconda3.sh -b -p /home/ec2-user/miniconda3 2> log_minicondash

echo ". /home/ec2-user/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
. /home/ec2-user/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
source /home/ec2-user/.bashrc

conda create -y --name python3

conda activate python3
```

I made the log files `log_miniconda` and `log_minicondash` to store any error messages.

`log_miniconda` shows that the Miniconda installer is actually downloaded:

```
 68750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99%  211M 0s
 68800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99%  250M 0s
 68850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99%  272M 0s
 68900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99% 4.74M 0s
 68950K                                                       100%  548G=0.9s

2023-06-30 03:54:53 (78.7 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/miniconda3.sh’ saved [70605094/70605094]
```

but `log_minicondash` shows the following error:

```
/tmp/miniconda3.sh: line 29: HOME: unbound variable
```

AWS documentation says that user data scripts are executed as root, but I don't understand why even if I'm trying to change the user with `su - ec2-user`, the `$HOME` variable is not `/home/ec2-user`.

I have tried launching an instance without the UserData parameter and running the script step by step and it works, but when connecting to the instance I'm already user `ec2-user` so I guess that's why there is no issue with the `$HOME` variable in that case.

How can I change to user `ec2-user` and update the `$HOME` variable accordingly?

I tried to add `exec bash` after changing user but it just prevents the rest of the script to run. I also tried doing `HOME=/home/ec2-user` but it still shows the unbound variable error.

Comment: `su` in this way starts an interactive shell, it doesn't change the user for the current script. You could use `sudo -u ec2-user bash <<EOF` and put the rest of your script in the heredoc to be executed by `sudo`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! You can put it as the correct answer. I'm really not very familiar with syntax that goes from right to left, but as you said, I only had to add the rest of the code. One weird thing though is that after the line you suggested, I added `echo $HOME >> next_home_directory` and when I looked at the log file, it was blank. `EOF` solved the unbound variable problem, but I'm still confused about why the `$HOME` variable is not being updated. It's not necessary to solve that for my purpose, but I'm curious to discover the reason.

Comment: It's because $HOME is expanded before the sudo runs. You can stop this behavior by quoting the delimiter in the heredoc. eg `<<'EOF'`

Comment: THANK YOU! I have been looking for this fix for days. This works well with GCP too!