# GCP install conda on startup script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, startup

I'm trying to install conda on the first startup of the VM but am encountering error after error.
The startup script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
sleep 5
yes Y | sudo apt-get update

wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -P /home/user/
bash /home/user/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b
rm /home/user/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh  
/home/user/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash
source /home/user/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
eval "$(cat /home/user/.bashrc | tail -n +10)"

yes Y | conda create -n test python=3.8

conda activate test
```

If I run the above directly it works fine. However when it's run as a startup script I get the following in the log:

```
Aug 29 15:49:51 testconda google_metadata_script_runner[850]: startup-script: /home/user/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 29: HOME: unbound variable
Aug 29 15:49:51 testconda google_metadata_script_runner[850]: startup-script: bash: /home/user/miniconda3/bin/conda: No such file or directory
Aug 29 15:49:51 testconda google_metadata_script_runner[850]: startup-script: bash: /home/user/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory
Aug 29 15:49:51 testconda google_metadata_script_runner[850]: startup-script: bash: conda: command not found
Aug 29 15:49:51 testconda google_metadata_script_runner[850]: startup-script: bash: conda: command not found
Aug 29 15:49:51 testconda google_metadata_script_runner[850]: startup-script exit status 127
Aug 29 15:49:51 testconda google_metadata_script_runner[850]: Finished running startup scripts.
```

Could somebody help please? Really struggling to make a proper startup script in GCP work.

Comment: Notice the error that `HOME` is not defined. Conda appears to be expecting a user environment. Try creating the user `miniconda3` and setting the environment variable `HOME` to that path or maybe better run the install script as that user using the command `su`.

Comment: Another issue, do not save temporary/install files to `/home/user`. Specify the `/tmp` directory. Review how the file system is created for users. I doubt it is /home/user/USERNAME`.

Comment: Thank you, the suggestion of `su` sent me into the right direction to solve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I've found the answer here:
[Boto3 UserData script having unexpected behavior for $HOME variable when installing Miniconda in EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76586023/boto3-userdata-script-having-unexpected-behavior-for-home-variable-when-install)

The following startup script works! (user is my username)

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -u user bash <<EOF
cd /home/user/

wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /tmp/miniconda3.sh 2> log_miniconda
bash /tmp/miniconda3.sh -b -p /home/user/miniconda3 2> log_minicondash

/home/user/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash
source /home/user/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
source /home/user/.bashrc

conda create -y -n test python=3.8

conda activate test
EOF
```